# mysqli bind_result not necessary?

Tags: php, mysqli

in another topic I had a problem with my code and one friend told me that I cannot use bind_result() with PHP Data Objects. I always do things like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select id, user from posts limit 10");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $user); //no?


while($stmt->fetch()) {
 echo "$id - $user <br>";
}

$stmt->close();
```

is it wrong? how should I fetch mysqli data?
I don't find any anwers about this, just about PDO connections...

thank you friends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anything wrong with your preparation of the statement or use of parameters but I will give you advice to use parameter(?) query.There is number of reason few of them are dictate here :

- The main advantage of a parameterized query is that the query does
  not need to be prepared each time it is run. A good example of this
  is scrolling a master record while the detail is refreshed based on
  the new record. In this case you are essentially running the same
  query repeatedly, with different values in the WHERE clause. If you
  do this with a regular query, you will have to prepare the query each
  time. If you use a parameterized query, you prepare the query once.
  Then you can change the parameters, and execute the statement as many
  times as you wish without having to prepare the query again.
- With most Delphi query components, changing the SQL requires
  re-parsing it, and re-allocating space for the parameters. When you
  use a parameterized query, changing the parameters does not mean
  changing the SQL, and thus the SQL is not re-parsed, saving time.
- A parameterized query can be twice as fast in a situation like this.

Comment: oh, thank you for your answer! and the advice, I really appreciate this!